# Maven error Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository

Tags: maven-2

Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
 resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
 org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): SOCKS : authentication failed

Comment: why does it happen ? thanks in advance!